# About Galois branched covers of Riemann Surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I am reading [Giraud's notes](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/PMO/PDF/J_GIRAUD_1969-70.pdf) (sorry they are in French) on Riemann surfaces and I have some questions about the end of the fifth section.

To begin with, a branched cover $f: X \to Y$ of degree $n$ (i.e. for every $y$ in $Y$ the sum over its fibre of the ramification degrees is constant n) is said to be Galois if $n$ is the order of the group Aut(X/Y). My first questions is: what is this group? In regular Galois theory one has a field extension and the automorphisms are those that fix the base field. If I had a surjective map or something I could see $X$ as an extension of $Y$ or something like that but that is not necessarily true because $X$ nor $Y$ may not be connected. In other (also French) notes I found that an automorphism of $f$ is an automorphism $\varphi \in$ Aut($X$) such that $f\circ \varphi = f$. And the group of automorphisms of $f$ is denoted Aut($X/Y$). This could be, but I find this notation quite confusing because $f$ is nowhere to be found at it. Maybe it does not depend on $f$? Meaning if I have another branched cover $g$ then they are equal.

Then, corollary $5.10$ says that every branched covering $f:X \to Y$ of degree $n$ is a quotient of a Galois branched covering, but I cannot even start dreaming about understanding it because the previous definitions are not clear to me.

I would find quite handy some suggested bibliography that proves this statement being similar to Giraud's notes but no so messy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $Aut(X/Y)$ is indeed automorphisms of $X$ over $Y$, i.e. maps $\varphi:X\to X$ such that $f\circ\varphi=f$ for $f:X\to Y$ the map.

Comment: There is an equivalence of categories between Riemann surfaces together with branched covering maps, and fields which are finitely generated and of transcendance degree one over $\bf C$ together with field extensions (see chap. I of Hartshorne). The field corresponding to a Riemann surface is its function field. So Cor. 5.10 translates to the statement that a finite (separable) extension of fields can be embedded in a finite Galois extension. This is a standard result of Galois theory (take the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of a generator of the extension).